# Run unique methods in a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, for-loop, variables

I am writing a basic command line application in an online and very limited environment. How would I make a for loop that: defines a new object then runs a method from that object?

I already have this yet the method part returns a error. As stated earlier i'm using a very limited environment and it did not given any info on the error.

```
for z in range(5):
    for zz in range(7):
        globals()['variable{}{}'.format(z,zz)] = an_object.thing("parm", 2, False)
        globals()['variable{}{}'.format(z,zz)].hello_world()
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't see an error there. What is this 'very limited environment'? Can you test your code in a normal environment? If not, try step by step to find out where the error is: 1. create the object `an_object.thing("parm", 2, False)` 2. create many `thing` instances in a loop 3. add the `hello_world()` 4. or try without the loop: create one instance and run the `hello_world()`

Comment: By very limited environment I mean i can only use what they gave me which is and idle and the standard library. I could test in a normal environment yet the code must work in that one. The error I get is vague it says error variable00 line 4. Now usually it gives some detail like if its a value error and the short description.

Comment: This error message helps a little. The loop seems to be ok. Please try my step 4.

Comment: You shouldn't do this at all. Use a dictionary.